# unable to connect to docker container python flask app on a windows server 2016

Tags: python, docker, docker-for-windows

I have a simple Python Flask based application in a docker image and I created a container with port mapping

**docker run --name MypyFlskApp -p 5010:5000 flask-crud-rest-app**

when i try to access MypyFlskApp container from host machine ("http://127.0.0.1:5010") i am getting error "Unable to connect to the remote server" but when i find container IP(http://172.19.247.234:5000) and tried the same then i get the response.

not sure why the port mapping is not working.

Comment: Is your flask app listening on localhost by any chance? I think that's the default behaviour for flask

Comment: I have set my host in python file like this appMainInstance.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)

Comment: Docker file might shed some light on the issue

Answer (score 0):

from host machine instead of 127.0.0.1 ( localhost) i have used VM IP address then my PythonFlask App started responding. Not sure why it is not able to access with 127.0.0.1(localhost)